# Are GPG keys generated on windows as secure as ones generated on linux?

Tags: gnupg, random-number-generator

Under linux you run out of system Entropy when trying to generate GPG keys unless you use /dev/urandom.  Under windows, you get the speed of /dev/urandom without any tweaks.  Does windows have that much extra entropy, or are the keys just less secure?

This is a link that discusses /dev/urandom generating less secure keys for those that aren't familiar with why this might be a problem.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnupg/+bug/706011

Answer (score 1):

I would say it mostly depends on the entropy pool and how entropy is collected.

I found this:

> Microsoft Windows releases newer than 95A feature the CryptoAPI (CAPI)
>   API that gathers entropy in a similar fashion to Linux kernel's
>   /dev/random.[11] Windows's CryptoAPI uses the binary registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\RNG\Seed to store a
>   seeded value from all of its entropy sources.[12] Because CryptoAPI is
>   closed-source, some free and open source software applications running
>   on the Windows platform use other measures to get randomness. For
>   example, GnuPG, as of version 1.06, uses a variety of sources such as
>   the number of free bytes in memory that combined with a random seed
>   generate the desired randomness it needs.[13] Programmers using CAPI
>   can get entropy by calling CAPI's CryptGenRandom(), after properly
>   initialising it

I hope it helps or points you in the right direction to follow.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately I had seen that, but still don't know if they pass the test of true randomness....